# Two equal Joomla sites in different domains, behave differently

Tags: database, joomla, dns, host

I have a site and since a few days, it has a problem. My site is prosklitiria-mostracarta.gr

I make another "TEST" site. ellinixx.gr

When i already finish the ellinixx.gr site and WORKS PERFECT, i copy the ellinixx.gr site and the database to old site : prosklitiria-mostracarta.gr

Now the two sites must be the same, but i have problem.
try to see
http://ellinixx.gr/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=106&Itemid=116
and try to see
http://prosklitiria-mostracarta.gr/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=106&Itemid=116

The first site has 160+ photos, but the prosklitiria-mostracarta.gr site has LESS than 80 photos...

But the sites is Sames... Copy... And database too...
All are the sames...
why cannot display all the images ?

In localhost (local) the site works perfect. 
If i put it on other domain, it works perfect. 
But in domain prosklitiria-mostracarta.gr the site does NOT display all the images :(

Can someone help me...?

Comment: It's hard to know without knowing if the hosting is *exactly* the same. If just one PHP module has different settings, that is enough for the two sites not behaving the same way. can you check if everything in the hosting side is *exactly* the same?

Comment: yes everything is the same and in the hosting side. i call hosting carrier and they check it. everything is the same, but the mostracarta site has problem...

Comment: both of hosting domain are in the same server...

Comment: I just checked to see if the images are present in the one that doesn't show all and they are present. So my next question: how are you placing the images on the article?

Comment: I bet the two aren't exactly the same. When I move sites, I use this excelent (free) extension: http://www.akeebabackup.com it even creates an installer.

Comment: with a plugin names Simple Image Gallery Pro (by JoomlaWorks) (full payed varsion).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jackjoe has the answer - install Akeeba Backup and move the site again using that component. I move sites from our development server to live all the time and I've never had one fail when using Akeeba Backup.

How did you move the site? Something is obviously different or the site would be the same. The images are there, but SIG Pro isn't adding them to the article.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this tutorial a couple of times: [link to howtojoomla.net](http://www.howtojoomla.net/2006092217/how-tos/installation/how-to-move-your-joomla-site-to-a-new-server)